# How to sync trigger animations using Photon accurately?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

According to a note from Photon devs themselves that shows up when you attempt to set up a Photon Animator View with trigger parameters, Photon Animator View seems to not work well with trigger parameters (I read somewhere that it has a 40% drop rate, and my own tests show even worse results), and they even suggest us to use our own custom code using RPC's or RaiseEvents to achieve better results. How then do we go about syncing animations triggered by trigger parameters?

clarification edit:
Is there a reliable way to sync animations using trigger parameters with Photon or do we have to do it by ourselves using RaiseEvent or what not?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this class that can be used to sync animations (any animation, not just trigger animations). It uses RaiseEvent (it could be done with RPC too).

```
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using ExitGames.Client.Photon;

namespace Workbench.Wolfsbane.Multiplayer
{
  [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
  [RequireComponent(typeof(PhotonView))]
  public class NetworkedAnimation : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
  {
    #region private fields
    Animator anim;
    #endregion

    #region monobehaviours
    public override void OnEnable()
    {
      base.OnEnable();
      PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient.EventReceived += OnEvent;
    }

    public override void OnDisable()
    {
      base.OnDisable();
      PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient.EventReceived -= OnEvent;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
      anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region private methods
    private void OnEvent(EventData photonEvent)
    {
      byte eventCode = photonEvent.Code;
      if (eventCode == PlayAnimationEventCode)
      {
        object[] data = (object[])photonEvent.CustomData;
        int targetPhotonView = (int)data[0];
        if (targetPhotonView == this.photonView.ViewID)
        {
          string animatorParameter = (string)data[1];
          string parameterType = (string)data[2];
          object parameterValue = (object)data[3];
          switch (parameterType)
          {
            case "Trigger":
              anim.SetTrigger(animatorParameter);
              break;
            case "Bool":
              anim.SetBool(animatorParameter, (bool)parameterValue);
              break;
            case "Float":
              anim.SetFloat(animatorParameter, (float)parameterValue);
              break;
            case "Int":
              anim.SetInteger(animatorParameter, (int)parameterValue);
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    #endregion

    #region public methods

    public const byte PlayAnimationEventCode = 1;

    public void SendPlayAnimationEvent(int photonViewID, string animatorParameter, string parameterType, object parameterValue = null)
    {
      object[] content = new object[] { photonViewID, animatorParameter, parameterType, parameterValue };
      RaiseEventOptions raiseEventOptions = new RaiseEventOptions { Receivers = ReceiverGroup.All }; 
      PhotonNetwork.RaiseEvent(PlayAnimationEventCode, content, raiseEventOptions, SendOptions.SendReliable);
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

usage:

```
    // in some other script (that is on the same object)
      GetComponent<NetworkedAnimation>().SendPlayAnimationEvent(photonView.ViewID, animation, "Trigger");
```

Sending the correct photonviewId is crucial because RaiseEvents are called on ALL objects that subscribe to the event so you need a way to filter only the appropriate object. In my case I needed to sync player animations and since every player has a photonView on them I used photonView.viewID as a filter mechanism. Others might go a different direction and not use photonView to filter objects but maybe send the RaiseEvent or the RPC to a manager-level object that will then send the animation command to the appropriate object.